# How can I remove items from the "Look in:" combo box in Visual Studio's "Find and Replace" dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have inadvertantly added some entries to the "Find and Replace" dialog in Visual Studio 2010.  See picture below:

[image]

I want to remove \r\n, Double, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: How the heck did you add them? :)

Comment: I'm not even sure.  My best guess is that the focus was in that field when I was typing and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These entries are located in the following registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find
```

They will be prefixed with `Query` and then followed by a number.

Comment: It's simply ridiculous that you need to edit the registry to remove something from the "Look in" field. Thanks for this answer though.

Comment: Note that the entries came back after I deleted them using regedt32.exe, because I then closed a running Visual Studio instance, after doing a "Save All". So close VS before deleting them. And that further entries can be found in ...\Find\Named that still show up in "Look In". Did not try to remove those.

Comment: Such an entry is not present when you use VS 2017 (version 15.0).

Comment: @jciloa Visual Studio 2017 uses its own private registry hive. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119996/where-does-visual-studio-2017-store-its-config

Answer (score 5):

The location for those entries is:

> HKEY_USERS \ {user guid} \Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find

where ***[user guid]*** is the guid for the current user.

really I just searched the registry for some entries that I added by accident while testing if there was another way to remove them.

Comment: Such an entry is not present when you use VS 2017 (version 15.0).

Comment: Nitpick: Users don't have GUID, instead they have SIDs. A SID has a different format to a GUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier